# How to set a date field in salesforce to empty through salesforce bulk api from python

Tags: bulk-api, python, date-field

How can I use the Salesforce Bulk API from Python to set a date field in Salesforce to be empty/null for multiple records in a bulk operation?

I have tried with following

- `None` - request accepted and got success response, but in the salesforce UI still the field holds the date. Other string fields got updated which I sent through that request
- `""` - Same as None this empty quotes also accepted but not reflected in UI
- `'null'` - request accepted but error response as the date field will not accept '/null'/
- `"0001-01-01"` - request accepted but error response as the date field will not accept this date

So is there a way in salesforce bulk api to clear a date field which already holds a date?

Answer (score 0):

Sending the value '#N/A' for the date field helps to clear the existing date in salesforce UI.